# Send phpmailer email with html code

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I made a function that sends mails, but they interpret html code. How can I make it to send exact html code in the body? For instance, the user should receive `<strong>text</strong>` and not bolded 'strong'.

```
function sendmail($dest,$subj ,$htmlmessage,$textmessage) {
    $Mail = new PHPMailer( true );
    try{

        $Mail->IsSMTP(); // Use SMTP
        $Mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE; // enable SMTP authentication
        //$Mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // 2 to enable SMTP debug information

        $Mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // Sets SMTP server
        $Mail->Username = 'mymail@gmail.com'; // SMTP account username
        $Mail->Password = 'mypassword'; // SMTP account password
        $Mail->SMTPSecure  = "ssl"; //Secure conection
        $Mail->Port = 465; // set the SMTP port

        $Mail->SetFrom ( 'mymail@gmail.com', 'def' );
        $Mail->FromName    = 'myname';
        //$Mail->addReplyTo( 'mymail@gmail.com', 'Reply here' );

        $Mail->addAddress($dest, 'to' ); // To:
        $Mail->isHTML( false );

        $Mail->Subject=$subj;
        $Mail->Body=$htmlmessage;
        $Mail->AltBody=$textmessage;

        $Mail->Send();
    }
    catch ( phpmailerException $e ) {

        file_put_contents( 'Mailerrors.txt', $e->errorMessage() , FILE_APPEND );
        die( "Problem with emailing." );
    }
}
```

Here I send the mail

```
$dest='sendto@gmail.com';
$subj='hello';
$htmlmessage='this is the body<strong>asd</strong>';
$textmessage='this is the body';

sendmail($dest,$subj, $htmlmessage,$textmessage);
```

Note that the function does work and sends me emails, just they interpret the html code.

Comment: set `$Mail->isHTML( true );`

Comment: That still interprets the code as HTML.

Comment: try `$htmlmessage='<html><body>this is the body<strong>asd</strong></body></html>';`

Comment: That still interprets it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible solutions to this.

To send only plain text, just do this:

```
$mail->isHTML(false);
```

and **do not put anything in** `$mail->AltBody`. That way the message will be sent as plain text, even if it contains HTML markup.

If you only want part of your message body to escape HTML rendering, you can either use `htmlspecialchars` or wrap that portion of your markup in `<pre>` tags.

Applying `htmlspecialchars` to the whole message body is a bit pointless as it achieves a similar looking result to `isHTML(false)`, but far less efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I did it. All I had to do:

```
 $Mail->Body=htmlspecialchars($htmlmessage);
```

Not sure if it's a good idea, even though it works. I'm sure there must be another way, too.